# How to set up the issuer of the certificate is Microsoft testing root certificate authority?

Tags: windows, digital-signature, sign, portable-executable, signtool

I use makecert.exe to get a `KM_test1.cer`, and then run `signtool sign <myfile.dll>` to sign `myfile.dll`. but it failed when I run `signtool verify <myfile.dll>`.

```
C:\Windows\System32>>makecert.exe -r -pe -ss PrivateCertStore -n CN=KM_test1 KM_test1.cer
Successed

C:\Windows\System32>>certmgr.msc
// drop this.cer file to Personal store

C:\Windows\System32>>signtool sign /fd sha1 "myfile.dll"
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: myfile.dll

C:\Windows\System32>signtool verify /debug "myfile.dll"
Signature Index: 0 (Primary Signature)
Hash of file (sha1): 32AEC1684BEACFDA35755E7342ADDA4B5196BF40

Signing Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: KM_test1
    Issued by: KM_test1
    Expires:   Sun Jan 01 08:59:59 2040
    SHA1 hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCC62D5F31D39188206765D27

File is not timestamped.

SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root
        certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
```

[image]

I have a file that can pass `signtool vertify "correctFile.dll"` and work for my project. it prints the follow info:

```
C:\Windows\System32>signtool verify /debug correctFile.dll

Verifying: correctFile.dll

Signature Index: 0 (Primary Signature)
Hash of file (sha1): xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7445032578A8D7B6EFAC
Signing Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: Microsoft Testing Root Certificate Authority 2010
    Issued by: Microsoft Testing Root Certificate Authority 2010
    Expires:   Mon Jun 18 06:04:11 2035
    SHA1 hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6A76B8178FA215F344

        Issued to: Microsoft Testing PCA 2010
        Issued by: Microsoft Testing Root Certificate Authority 2010
        Expires:   Mon Jun 18 06:04:11 2035
        SHA1 hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxAFC0BE2F1D13AB21773

            Issued to: Microsoft Windows Publisher
            Issued by: Microsoft Testing PCA 2010
            Expires:   Mon Nov 28 02:21:47 2022
            SHA1 hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1305E8B85AC0BA257DDDF

File is not timestamped.


Successfully verified: correctFile.dll

Number of files successfully Verified: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0
```

i guess the problem is located in Signing Certificate Chain. Maybe it will work if i set the issuer of certificate is Microsoft Testing Root Certificate Authority 2010. So, does anyone have an idea about this issue?
[image: i want my certificate like this.]

Comment: *Microsoft Testing Root Certificate Authority 2010* usually was in trusted root cert store. are you can by self sign file to this root ? anyway signtool verify accept only 5 root certs: 1. *Microsoft Root Authority* 2. *Microsoft Root Certificate Authority* 3. *Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010* 4. *Microsoft Test Root Authority* 5. *Microsoft Testing Root Certificate Authority 2010*

Comment: I have no idea how to self sign file to those root certs, do you have some reference links for it or can tell me how to solve it?

Comment: You can not self sign it to it. Only ms. Unclear for what you need this at all. For what you run signtool verify.